# git command to override branchC with branchA without merge

Tags: git

If `branchC` has code from `branchB`. And `branchA` needs to make `branchC` an exact replica of itself irrespective of what is deployed on `branchC`. Get rid of whatever is deployed and just make the target branch `branchC` a self-replica.

What is the command to do this? What's the neat/clean way to do it. We do not want any merges/conflicts or anything to do with what was deployed earlier on `branchC`. Every time the given command should run,

```
source branch should override the target branch code (effectively creating a replica of itself in the target branch)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
git branch -f branchC branchA
```

Comment: or `git checkout -B branchC branchA` in case `branchC` is currently checked out, either way rehangs the `branchC` label on the `branchA` tip but Git won't rehang your currently-checked-out branch ref unless you use reset or checkout -B.